# storing in app purchase value in keychain using third party library

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, keychain

I have an application in which I am incorporating in-app purchase and I am using [SwiftyStoreKit](https://github.com/bizz84/SwiftyStoreKit) which works fantastically well. the whole in-app purchase works fine but the problem I am facing now is I have some disabled buttons that I would like to enable once a user makes a purchase and the purchase is successful. Using Userdefaults could be an easy route but it is not secure and as such I felt using `keychain` was better so I decided to incorporate keychain with this third-party library [KeychainAccess](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/KeychainAccess) into my app, and my code looks like this below

```
func setNonConsumablePurchase(_ status: Bool, identifier: String?) {

        let keychain = Keychain(service: "com.companyname.appname.iapService")
        guard let identifier = identifier else {return}
        UserDefaults.standard.set(status, forKey: "nonConsumablePurchaseWasMade")
        do {
            try keychain.set("purchased", key: IAPsConfig.appBundle + "." + identifier)
            }
            catch let error {
                print("setting keychain to purchased failed")
                print(error)
            }
    }

    func isProductPurchased(identifier: IAPsConfig.RegisteredPurchase, completion: @escaping CompletionHandler) {

        let keychain = Keychain(service: "com.companyname.appname.iapService")
        let value = IAPsConfig.appBundle + "." + identifier.rawValue


        // if there is value correspond to the productIdentifier key in the keychain
        if (try? keychain.get(identifier.rawValue)) == value{

            completion(true)

        } else {
            // the product has not been purchased previously, do nothing
            print("Not purchased: \(identifier)")
        }

    }



    func purchase(viewController: UIViewController, purchase: IAPsConfig.RegisteredPurchase, sharedSecret: String, type: IAPsConfig.PurchaseType, atomically: Bool, validDuration: TimeInterval? = nil) -> Void {


        NetworkActivityIndicatorManager.networkOperationStarted()
        if type == .simple {
            SwiftyStoreKit.retrieveProductsInfo([IAPsConfig.appBundle + "." + purchase.rawValue]) { result in
                if let product = result.retrievedProducts.first {
                    SwiftyStoreKit.purchaseProduct(product, quantity: 1, atomically: atomically) { result in

                        NetworkActivityIndicatorManager.networkOperationFinished()

                        if case .success(let purchased) = result {
                            let downloads = purchased.transaction.downloads
                            if !downloads.isEmpty {
                                SwiftyStoreKit.start(downloads)
                            }
                            self.setNonConsumablePurchase(true, identifier: purchase.rawValue)
                            // Deliver content from server, then:
                            if purchased.needsFinishTransaction {
                                SwiftyStoreKit.finishTransaction(purchased.transaction)
                            }
                        }
                        if let alert = IAPAlerts.instance.alertForPurchaseResult(result) {
                            self.showAlert(alert, viewController: viewController)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {

            SwiftyStoreKit.purchaseProduct(IAPsConfig.appBundle + "." + purchase.rawValue, atomically: atomically) { result in
                NetworkActivityIndicatorManager.networkOperationFinished()

                if case .success(let purchased) = result {
                    let downloads = purchased.transaction.downloads
                    if !downloads.isEmpty {
                        SwiftyStoreKit.start(downloads)
                    }
                    self.setNonConsumablePurchase(true, identifier: purchase.rawValue)
                    // Deliver content from server, then:
                    if purchased.needsFinishTransaction {
                        SwiftyStoreKit.finishTransaction(purchased.transaction)
                    }
                }

                if let alert = IAPAlerts.instance.alertForPurchaseResult(result) {
                    self.showAlert(alert, viewController: viewController)
                }

                guard let validDuration = validDuration else {return}
                self.verifyPurchase(viewController: viewController, purchase, validDuration: validDuration)
            }
        }

    }
```

my viewcontroller i did

```
 @IBAction func buyAutoRenew1(_ sender: Any) {
        IAPServices.instance.purchase(viewController: self, purchase: .Subscription1, sharedSecret: IAPsConfig.sharedSecret, type: .autoRenew, atomically: true, validDuration: TimeInterval(60))
    }

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        IAPServices.instance.isProductPurchased(identifier: .Subscription1) { (success) in

            if success {
                print("BOUGHT ALREADY")
            } else {
                print("Not BOUGHT AT ALL")
            }
        }
    }
```

after purchasing and loading up the Viewcontroller again, I still got

`Not purchased: Subscription1`

I do not know what I am doing wrong and would be glad if anyone could point me in the right direction

Comment: If most - if not much more - feel that `UserDefaults` is the right way to handle things, why do you feel otherwise? How do you plan to handle everything from iOS updates (and testing) to restoring purchases? Seems to me that you are not only over-complicating things, you're reinventing the wheel.

Comment: user defaults could be easily by passed from the research I made that is why.

Comment: thanks for your input. I would use UserDefaults

Comment: Did you manage to solve your problem with keychain access?